# Is assignment of strings valid?

Tags: c, string, character

Is `s1=s2` valid statement? It give me error:

> lvalue required

My code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
void main()
{
    char s[1]="integ";
    char s[2]="systems";
    s1=s2;
    printf("%s", s1);
    getch();
}
```

Comment: One thing to keep in mind, at least with C, is that a string is simply a pointer to char.  Copying a address to a pointer is not the same as copying the contents.

Comment: it is `char s1[]` and `char s2[]`...sorry was a typo...now tell me wats wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You haven't defined a variable called `s2`. You have two variables, `s1`, and `s`. Also, you can't assign character arrays like that. Declare them as pointers if you need to change the array the variable points to after initialization, or else use `strcpy()` to copy one string's contents into another (being careful about overflow of course). Finally, you're declaring `s` with a size of 2, then initializing it with a string that is 7 characters long. Try:

```
char *s1 = "integ";
char *s2 = "systems";
s1 = s2;
printf(%s", s1);
```